# How to specify different ports for different controller in an asp.net MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, web, asp.net-web-api

How to specify different ports for different controller in an asp.net MVC application?

I have two controllers I want to run one controller on port 80 and another on 8123.

I dont have the option of creating two separate web applications and hosting them on different ports.

Is there any way I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO, because the Port number is the gateway for the internet to the web server. When the HttpRequest hits your server, IIS will route the request to a web application hosted on the web server and then find the resource  or file within the web application. Hope you notice the hierarchy, Internet -> IIS server -> Web Application -> Resources. The MVC controller is within the ASP.NET MVC web application and that is why you cannot. If you can, I guess you will have to do a lot of work.